# Should I use connect or hooks for react redux and which has better performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using react-redux for my react project, apparently, there are 2 ways to use the redux state
`connect` or `useSelector`,

My redux store has a reducer for each page,

For Home Page > `homePageReducer`

For Message Page > `messagePageReducer`

For Authentication > `authReducer`

For User's blog > `blogReducer`

For Settings > `userSettingsReducer`

For User's Profile > `userProfileReducer`

In my top-level component or the main component, I have used a selector hook to get all the reducer and passed down the reducers as props to the required components

```js
const {home, messages, auth, settings, blogs} = useSelector( (state:RootState) => state)

return(
<main>
     <Switch>
         <Route exact to={HOME_ROUTE}>
              <HomeApp auth={auth} settings={settings} userProfile={userProfile}/>
         </Route>
         <Route exact to={CHAT_ROUTE}>
              <ChatApp auth={auth} messages={messages} userProfile={userProfile}/>
         </Route>
         <Route exact to={BLOG_ROUTE}>
              <BlogApp auth={auth} blogs={blogs} userProfile={userProfile}/>
         </Route>
     </Switch>
</main>
)
```

Is it a good architecture for my project and bring no performance issue for my project or should I use `connect` or `useSelector  hook` inside those components?
What is better?

Comment: `connect` is considered to be the old way only used for class components. If your components are made as functional components then you can not use connect and should use hooks. A problem with your current approach is that since your main component is "subscribing" to *every* object in state (`home`, `messages`, `auth`, `settings`, `blogs`), a change in any of those will trigger a full re-render, even for the components that did not have their values changed.

Comment: So in short, use hooks/`useSelector`, and your components themselves should be responsible for getting that data from redux store, not your main/parent component

Comment: @nbokmans I agree with you on everything but function components *can* use `connect`.  It's better to use hooks though!

Comment: @Khan you can find all of the recommended best practices in the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide)

Comment: @LindaPaiste interesting, didn't know that, thanks for letting me knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux has a very useful [Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide) explaining all of the current best practices.  There are a few recommendations on that list that are applicable to your example.

---

#### [Use the React-Redux Hooks API](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api)

> Prefer using the React-Redux hooks API (`useSelector` and `useDispatch`) as the default way to interact with a Redux store from your React components.

---

#### [Connect More Components to Read Data from the Store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store)

> Prefer having more UI components subscribed to the Redux store and reading data at a more granular level. This typically leads to better UI performance, as fewer components will need to render when a given piece of state changes.

---

#### [Call useSelector Multiple Times in Function Components](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#call-useselector-multiple-times-in-function-components)

> When retrieving data using the `useSelector` hook, prefer calling `useSelector` many times and retrieving smaller amounts of data, instead of having a single larger `useSelector` call that returns multiple results in an object.

---

You definitely want to use `useSelector`.  Rather than selecting everything in the parent and passing it down, your `Route` render components should take no props and get everything that they need from Redux themselves.

```
const App = {
  return(
     <Switch>
         <Route exact to={HOME_ROUTE}>
              <HomeApp />
         </Route>
         <Route exact to={CHAT_ROUTE}>
              <ChatApp />
         </Route>
         <Route exact to={BLOG_ROUTE}>
              <BlogApp />
         </Route>
     </Switch>
  )
}
```

```
const HomeApp = () => {
  const userProfile = useSelector( (state: RootState) => state.user );

  // We probably don't need the whole auth object
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector( (state: RootState) => !! state.auth );

  // Do you need to return *every* setting?  Just select what you need.
  const settings = useSelector( (state: RootState) => state.settings );
 
  ...
}
```

You might want to [create selector functions](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-selector-functions-to-read-from-store-state) especially for commonly-accessed values like `userProfile`.

An alternative to modifying the current components `HomeApp` etc. would be to create a `HomeScreen` component as a wrapper around `HomeApp` and keep `HomeApp` as a pure presentational component.  `HomeScreen` would get all of the data from Redux and call `HomeApp` with the correct props.